# Carregar javascript dependendo do viewport?

Tags: javascript, mobile, layout-responsivo, viewport

É possível minimizar o *download* de javascript dependendo do *viewport*?

Posso colocar arquivos CSS diferentes para serem carregado apenas verificando o tamanho do *viewport* por exemplo.

Estou com um projeto de loja virtual que querem muitas animações e efeitos na loja para *desktop*, porém obviamente quando carregar a versão *mobile* ele iria baixar todos o código js e eu queria separa em 2, mobile.js (max 600px), desktop.js e o navegador só baixaria apenas a versão "necessária".

Seria meio que um *import* do CSS só que para JS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  @import url(desktop.css);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  @import url(mobile.css);
}
```

Pesquisei sobre o assunto e não achei nada, me desculpem se é algo simples, mas as maneiras que tentei não funcionaram.

Comment: Em que linguagem é desenvolvido o projeto?

Comment: Estou fazendo só o front em html, js e css.
Porém o sistema já utilizado pela loja é ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar os `@media width` e `@media height` via Javascript cross-browser e cross-devices:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
```

Fonte: [Resposta aceita do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript/8876069#8876069)

---

**EDIT**

Como você quer que trazer um JS dinamicamente a depender do viewport, eu sugiro que você coloque este script no final do seu `<body>` no HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var $width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

    var $script = document.createElement("script");
    $script.setAttribute("src", $width > 600 ? "desktop.js" : "mobile.js");
    document.body.appendChild($script);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Mas fazendo isso o browser vai carregar o js inteiro e separar apenas a exibição, correto? 
O que quero é que não carregue o código desktop quando visto em mobile (max 600px).

Comment: Editei a minha resposta para fazer o load do script de acordo com a largura.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução viável é detectar o `user-agent` e determinar se pertence a um *browser mobile* ou não. O site [Detect Mobile Browser](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) possui *scripts* em várias linguagens.

Exemplo em **PHP**:

```
<?php
$isMobile = (preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4)))

if ($isMobile)
   echo '<script src="/js/meuarquivo.js"></script>';
```

O projeto [Detect Mobile](http://mobiledetect.net/) para PHP dá muito mais opções, e poderia fazer o mesmo do código acima em bem "menos" código:

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
   echo '<script src="/js/meuarquivo.js"></script>'; 
}
```

Outra solução um pouco mais rustica é referenciar os arquivos no próprio **Javascript**:

```js
var isMobile = (function(a){return /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4));})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

if (isMobile) {
    console.log('Dispositivo Móvel, jQuery não carregado');
}
else {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js');
   document.head.appendChild(script);

}

if (!isMobile)
   setTimeout(function(){$('#log').text('Dispositivo Desktop, jQuery carregado');}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

**Obs:** Neste exemplo eu coloquei um `setTimeout` para esperar o download do javascript. Em situações reais o código de carrega os *scripts* pode estar direto no `head` e o uso dentro de um `$(document).ready(...)` (tendo por primícia que o jQuery sempre será carregado diretamente).