# Impedir execução de .js no mobile

Tags: php, html

"Não e uma duplicata pois não quero medir o tamanho da página, quero verificar o dispositivo através de alguma função."

Seguinte estou querendo impedir que um arquivo .js seja lido no mobile, quero que ele execute apenas no desktop.

O problema e que estou usando cache no site e ele gera arquivos estático em html das paginas, e o conteúdo que e exibido no desktop acaba aparecendo no mobile.

Antes eu tinha controle sobre isso pois o site não tinha cache, mas como as visitas subiram foi necessário seu uso para o servidor aguentar.

É possível fazer algo parecido usando alguma função que possa ser usada diretamente no `html` como `javascript`?

Este era o codigo usado:

```
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$symbian =  strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Symbian");

if ($iphone || $ipad || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $symbian == true) {
// 
} else {
//
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Carregar javascript dependendo do viewport?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78276/carregar-javascript-dependendo-do-viewport)

Comment: Chegou a ler as respostas? Lá tem o que você procura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o seu problema esta na estrutura que pensou para o cache, acredite, eu tenho uma estrutura semelhante a sua que uso nos sites de meus clientes, o que eu fiz para resolver foi adicionar um sufixo quando for mobile e outro quando for desktop, assim evita de carregar o **cache back-end** no tipo de user-agent diferente

Ou seja, a solução do sufixo serve para diferenciar os estáticos para celular dos para Desktop. Claro que você pode fazer uma abordagem via JavaScript, aqui estou apenas apresentando como resolver o que você já possui.

A outra sugestão seria usar media-queries e resolver tudo via CSS, mas neste caso teria que remodelar o HTML também.

Ficou algo como:

**global.php**

```
<?php

function is_mobile() {
   //Se não tiver user-agent definido retorna false/assume como desktop
   if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return false;

   //Com regex checa as palavras que possivelmente o usuário esta acessando via celular
   return preg_match('#iPhone|Android|webOS#', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) > 0;
}

//Cache de 3600 segundos/mesmo que 1 hora de cache
$cachelimite = 3600;

//Sufixo para Desktop/padrão
$sufixo = '.desktop.html';  

if (is_mobile()) {
    //Troca o sufixo se for celular
    $sufixo = '.mobile.html';        
}

//Define a pasta aonde deve ser salvo os estáticos, você pode ajustar
$cachefolder = 'cachepages/';

//Captura a URL com querystring
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

//Gera o caminho do arquivo
$cachefile = realpath($cachefolder . strlen($url) . '_' . sha1($url) . $sufixo);

//verifica se o cache existe e se expirou o tempo limite
if (is_file($cachefile) && filemtime($cachefile) + $cachelimite > time()) {
    readfile($cachefile);
    exit;
}

//Inicia a captura do buffer
ob_start();

register_shutdown_function(function () use ($cachefile) {
    //gravar o buffer no arquivo estático
    file_put_contents($cachefile, ob_get_contents());
});
```

> Note que o `sha1` ali foi somente de exemplo, assim como o md5 o sha1 também pode conflitar, a ideia é só um exemplo básico para entender a lógica, você pode futuramente adaptar isto.

Páginas recebem isto:

```
<?php

require_once 'global.php';
```

---

então o que resolve o problema de carregar o cache é isto:

```
$sulfixo = '.desktop.html';  

if (is_mobile()) {
    $sulfixo = '.mobile.html';        
}
```

Claro que fiz uma regex simplificada de detectar o user-agent:

```
 return preg_match('#iPhone|Android|webOS#', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) > 0;
```

Mas é somente para ilustrar, no caso você pode melhorar ela ou adaptar a sua necessidade, usando o separador pipe `|` na expressão regular.